# How can I tally my data such that the correspondence of my data simplifies like an OR operation?

Tags: python, list

I have here an array of data from sites. It either says that the site is normal or alarm or offline. Normal is the same as alarm or "Online". How can I automatically generate an output such that gives me the site and its corresponding status.

The way that the status simplifies is like an OR operation. As long as there is "normal" or "alarm" status for any similar site, the output would be [site1, "Online"]. Otherwise, "Offline".

```
[site1, "normal"],
[site1, "offline"],
[site1, "alarm"],
[site2, "offline"],
[site3, "normal"],
[site3, "alarm"],
[site3, "offline"]
```

I'm not sure how to wrap the data on the status. Any ideas?

Here is the sample output from the given sample input data:

```
site1 Online
site2 Offline
site3 Online
```

Comment: For your particular case it would be much simpler to output `Offline` if the status is `"offline"`,  or else output `Online` for any other statuses. Use a dict if the status mapping becomes more complex.

Comment: Thanks @blhsing. I'll try using dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dictionary to hold `{site: status}`. The status is assumed to be "offline". Only when we see "online" or "alarm" that we turn it "online"

Code:

```py
data = [
    ["site1", "normal"],
    ["site1", "offline"],
    ["site1", "alarm"],
    ["site2", "offline"],
    ["site3", "normal"],
    ["site3", "alarm"],
    ["site3", "offline"]
]

states = {}
for site, status in data:
    states.setdefault(site, "offline")
    if status == "normal" or status == "alarm":
        states[site] = "online"

for site, status in states.items():
    print(f"{site}: {status}")
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that solves it entirely and it's much much more cleaner.